# Shutdown hangs, screen freezed while the computer is processing shutdown

Tags: mount, 22.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and the shutdown process freezes. I always have to force it by pressing the power button.

I tried:

- apt update/upgrade
- set acpi=force in GRUB
- Update BIOS/UEFI
- Disable Virtualization

shutdown process log, the last lines where the shutdown freezes:

```
K1 Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-partuuid/47ddce4
OK 1 Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:02:00.0-nvme-1-part3.
OK 1 Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-KINGSTON_OM8PDP3512B-AI1_50026876858E
OK] Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.0026b76858edb1b5-part3. 
OK ] Deactivated swap /dev/nvme0n1p3.
OK 1 Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/fcf15b5f-e353-48e8-99be-285df2a4d3d5.
OK 1 Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
OK 1 Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
OK ] Finished System Power Off.
OK 1 Reached target System Power Off.
[174.904560] systemd-shutdown [1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices. 
[174.911218] systemd-shutdown [1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes... 
[174.913596] systemd-journald [347]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdown). 
[174.928757] systemd-shutdown [1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[174.931926] systemd-shutdown [1]: Unmounting file systems.
[174.932858] [6373]: Remounting '/' read-only in with options 'errors=remount-ro'. 
[174.950445] EXT4-fs (nvmeon1p4): re-mounted e402ee5d-c738-49f8-9f04-72512e57e5ca. Qu 
[174.952715] systemd-shutdown [1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[174.953346] systemd-shutdown [1]: Deactivating swaps. 
[174.953996] systemd-shutdown [1]: All swaps deactivated. 
[174.955069] systemd-shutdown [1]: Detaching loop devices. 
[174.956880] systemd-shutdown [1]: All loop devices detached. 
[174.957509] systemd-shutdown [1]: Stopping MD devices. 
[174.958161) systemd-shutdown [1]: All MD devices stopped. 
[174.958697] systemd-shutdown [1]: Detaching DM devices.
[174.959475) systemd-shutdown [1]: All DM devices detached.
[174.959979] systemd-shutdown [1]: All filesystems, swaps, loop devices, HD devices and 
[174.982556] systemd-shutdown [1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[174.982875] systemd-shutdown [1]: Powering off.
[174.988850] kvm exiting hardware virtualization
```